# 'Unexpected Token {' error with ES6 Import and Export syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use a boolean across 2 javascript files(one that exports the bool and one that imports it). I use `export isReady`('isReady' being the boolean name) for the first file, and I use `import { isReady } from './otherfile.js';` on the other file. They still give the same error, usually lying in the `import` syntax.

Comment: How are you using this file?  Are you using `<script type="module" src="file-doing-import.js"></script>`?

Comment: Might want to see the actual syntax in both files...

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add `type="module"` to the html `<script>` element. Thanks to @zero298 's comment. It gave a few extra errors, but they were easy to resolve. Thanks!